# Definite Integral Resulting in $ln(f(x))$ with $f(x_2)=-1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

I have the following problem:
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = a*y(x)-1$$ over $x$ from $x_1$ to $x_2$

We know $y(x_2) = 0$

I can solve the separation of variables to get:
$$\frac{1}{a}*ln(a*y(x_2)-1) - \frac{1}{a}*ln(a*y(x_1)-1) = x_2-x_1$$
But how do I evaluate it form here since:
$ln(a*Y(x_2)-1) = ln(-1)$ and is undefined. Does the whole term fall to zero?

Answer (score 0):

Let us go back through your steps. Starting with $$\frac{d y}{dx} = ay-1$$ you separated the variables to get  $$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac 1{ay-1}$$ that is to say $$dx=\frac {dy}{ay-1}=\frac 1 a\frac {a}{ay-1}dy$$ Integrating both sides, you then get $$x+C=\frac 1 a \log(ay-1)$$ or $$e^{a(x+C)}=ay-1=K e^{ax}$$ which by the end write $$y=c_1 e^{a x}+\frac{1}{a}$$ Now, apply the condition $y(x_2)=0$ to obtain the value of constant $c_1$.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks Claude - I am trying to solve for a proof of:
$$y = \frac{1}{a}*(1+e^\left(-a(x_2 - x_1)\right))$$
My steps were:
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = a*y(x)-1$$ 
$$\frac{\partial y}{a*y-1} = \partial x$$
$$\int_{y(x_1)}^{y(x_2)}  \frac{\partial y}{a*y-1} = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \partial x$$
$$\frac{1}{a} ln(y-1)| _{y(x_1)}^{y(x_2)} = x_2 - x_1$$
$$\frac{1}{a}ln(y(x_2)-1) - \frac{1}{a}ln(y(x_1)-1) = x_2 - x_1$$

Which if I let $\frac{1}{a}ln(y(x_2)-1) = 0$ , folds in to the required proof.

x is actually time, t, if that helps?

Comment: You must work with $y$ and not with any $\log(.)$. Do not integrate with bounds; just get $y(x)$ with the condition $y(x_2)=0$.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks Claude

Comment: @Matt. Good to know !! Cheers :-)